# using CASE to select column for SET in UPDATE statement IN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case

I want to execute the following statement. Is it possible to select which column to update using the CASE ?

```
UPDATE TABVAR CASE 
WHEN M BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN SET M0_TO_6 = M
WHEN M BETWEEN 7 AND 18 THEN SET M7_TO_18 = M
WHEN M BETWEEN 19 AND 54 THEN SET M19_TO_54 = M
WHEN M > 54 THEN SET MABOVE54 = M
END
```

Comment: @JamesZ's solution will work for you, but I'm as curious as Martin is why you have the four columns. It looks like ages to me: children, young adults, adults, seniors. What happens when someone who's `M7_TO_18` turns 19?

Comment: @EdGibbs. It's a kind of a report that I need to create for which I need to display the data that way. And it's not ages, it's no_of_months and it's gonna be used on a monthly basis and not more than that. So it won't be a great deal if there's some data change.

Comment: @MartinSmith. They would be computed columns, but I am trying to get a better option to improve the performance since the data's gonna be massive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a `case` expression like that, only to return an (l-)value. You could, however, emulate such a behavior with a `case` expression for each column:

```
UPDATE tabvar
SET 
m0_to_6 = CASE WHEN m BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN m ELSE m0_to_6 END,
m7_to_18 = CASE WHEN m BETWEEN 7 AND 18 THEN m ELSE m7_to_18 END,
m19_to_54 = CASE WHEN m BETWEEN 19 AND 54 THEN m ELSE m19_to_54 END, 
mabove54 = CASE WHEN m > 54 THEN m ELSE mabove54 END
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.  The solutions given by all above are already known to me. Apologies for not disclosing that. I wasn't sure if the SET statement can be integrated into the CASE the way I want. Hence, I needed to know.

Answer (score 6):

Not that way, but you could do basically same thing like this:

```
UPDATE TABVAR
set 
  M0_TO_6 = CASE WHEN M BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN M else M0_TO_6 end,
  M7_TO_18 = CASE WHEN M BETWEEN 7 AND 18 THEN M else M7_TO_18 END,
  ...
```

This way you're updating either the value M to the column, or the value that already exists in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this type of query:

```
UPDATE TABVAR 
SET M0_TO_6 = CASE WHEN M BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN M ELSE M0_TO_6 END,
    M7_TO_18 = CASE WHEN M BETWEEN 7 AND 18 THEN M ELSE M7_TO_18 END,
    M19_TO_54 = CASE WHEN M BETWEEN 19 AND 54 THEN M ELSE M19_TO_54 END,
    MABOVE54 = CASE WHEN M > 54 THEN M ELSE MABOVE54 END
```